# equivalent of value_counts of Pandas in NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count

Pandas's `value_counts` function outputs the counts of each element in a Pandas series.

If I need to count each unique elements of a list, I need to make it into a Pandas series and then call the `value_counts` function.

Is there a function that does the same thing in NumPy?

Answer (score 10):

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns the unique elements of an array, but it also has an optional `return_counts` parameter which causes `np.unique` to return both the unique elements *and* for each unique element, the number of times it appeared in the original array, like Pandas's `value_counts`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
>>> unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
>>> unique
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> counts
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
```